# The usage of 的 at the end of the sentence

Tags: simplified-characters

（那件衣服可不是我洗的）我洗衣服很干净的。

Can someone try to explain to me the function of 的 at The end the sentence "我洗衣服很干净的"?
Shouldn't it have been “我衣服洗得很干净”. Does “我洗衣服很干净的” follow any pattern/structure?
Thank you.

Comment: look up the topic ＂语气助词＂ （modal particles）in any Chinese grammar，e。g。in ＂实用现代汉语语法＂：４２７页：五、的：＂的＂用于陈述句末，可以加强肯定语气，谓语前往往还用＂是＂（参见第四编第三章第二节＂是。。。的＂句（二））（also look up the topic 是。。。的 sentence）例如：（１）放心吧，你的病会好的。（２）他一定会回来的。（３）我是同意你的意见的。

Comment: how to find additional references： google e。g。＂Chinese grammar， modal particle  的＂， one result：http://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/%22De%22_%28modal_particle%29

Comment: [Why is 的 used in these sentences?](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/3181/why-is-%E7%9A%84-used-in-these-sentences) already contains a similar discussion. Please consider in the future using the search box on the top right of the page to check whether a similar question has already been asked.

Answer (score 2):

To perform the meaning in the given context below sentences would be useful:

> 1.我衣服洗得很干净   (100% perfect correct, native chinese , popular sentence )
>
> 2.我衣服洗得很干净 (的)/(滴)/(啦)/(哟)/(呐)/(呀)  etc...
>   ( only to emphasize, no additional meaning. )
>
> 3.我洗(过)(的)衣服很干净  (native, perfect,popular )
>
> 4.我**的**衣服洗**得**很干净 (native,perfect,popular, 4 is the full sentence of 1)
>
> 5.我洗衣服/很干净的  ( olny a bit weird but most ppl understand)
>
> 6.我洗衣服(的过程)是很干净的 (native,perfect,popular, 6 is improvement of 5)

if you only want a shortcut, following the most popular way native speaker says will be more useful than researching on Chinese grammars stuff.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, 干净 is an adjective, so 很干净 can't be used to modify the action 洗衣服.

- 我洗衣服很干净
  Orally OK, but feels little bit odd. Adding 的 is good practice. Here 的 links 干净 to 衣服
- 我洗衣服很费水/很卖力/很勤快
  This is normal, as 费水 etc describes 洗衣服. Adding 的 on the end is also fine in the sense @S.Rhee pointed out
- 我洗的衣服很干净
  Normal as well. 干净 describes 衣服. Adding 的 is also fine as well